# How to restrict apps to install in iphone/android Jailbroken devices from Appstore/Googleplaystore?

Tags: android, ios

I need to control my application not to install in the jailbroken devices from App Store.

Answer (score 1):

From the iOS side, you can not stop users with jailbroken devices from downloading your app from the app store.  I am certain that you can not stop it from the Android side as well but I would need someone to verify this.  Perhaps you are having a specific problem in mind which has lead to your solution of stopping users from downloading your app on rooted or jailbroken devices.  How about asking the original question which lead you to this solution and someone may be able to help.